# Aws lambda , dynamodb error after deolayment : UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host at port `8008'. This service may not be available in the `eu-west-1'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am testing a fass (function as  a service ) using AWS lambda

I am getting  following error on testing the api after serverless deploy

> query-error: UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: 'localhost' at port `8008'. This service may not be available in the 'eu-west-1' region.","status":"error"}"

but when running in the local using serverless offline everything works as expected

what could be the reason for this error?

also in the server validation error works if wrong params are passed, this error shows up when query is being executed

**serveless.ts**

```
/* eslint no-use-before-define: 0 */

import type { AWS } from "@serverless/typescript";

// DynamoDB
import dynamoDbTables from "./resources/dynamodb-tables";

// Functions
import functions from "./resources/functions";

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: "lead-management-app",
  frameworkVersion: "2",
  custom: {
    region: "${opt:region, self:provider.region}",
    stage: "${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
    prefix: "${self:service}-${self:custom.stage}",
    lead_table: "${self:service}-leads-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
    interest_table:
      "${self:service}-interests-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}",
    table_throughputs: {
      prod: 5,
      default: 1,
    },
    table_throughput:
      "${self:custom.table_throughputs.${self:custom.stage}, self:custom.table_throughputs.default}",
    dynamodb: {
      stages: ["dev"],
      start: {
        port: 8008,
        inMemory: true,
        heapInitial: "200m",
        heapMax: "1g",
        migrate: true,
        seed: true,
        convertEmptyValues: true,
        // Uncomment only if you already have a DynamoDB running locally
        // noStart: true
      },
    },
    ["serverless-offline"]: {
      httpPort: 3000,
      babelOptions: {
        presets: ["env"],
      },
    },
    profile: {
      prod: "prodAccount",
      dev: "devAccount",
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    "serverless-bundle",
    "serverless-dynamodb-local",
    "serverless-offline",
    "serverless-dotenv-plugin",
  ],
  provider: {
    name: "aws",
    runtime: "nodejs14.x",
    stage: "dev",
    region: "eu-west-1",
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: "1",
      NODE_OPTIONS: "--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000",
      REGION: "${self:custom.region}",
      STAGE: "${self:custom.stage}",
      LEADS_TABLE: "${self:custom.lead_table}",
      INTERESTS_TABLE: "${self:custom.interest_table}",
    },
    iamRoleStatements: [
      {
        Effect: "Allow",
        Action: [
          "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
          "dynamodb:Query",
          "dynamodb:Scan",
          "dynamodb:GetItem",
          "dynamodb:PutItem",
          "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
          "dynamodb:DeleteItem",
        ],
        Resource: [
          { "Fn::GetAtt": ["LeadsTable", "Arn"] },
          { "Fn::GetAtt": ["InterestsTable", "Arn"] },
        ],
      },
    ],
    profile: "${self:custom.profile.${self:custom.stage}}",
    lambdaHashingVersion: "20201221",
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions,
  package: { individually: true },
  resources: {
    Resources: dynamoDbTables,
  },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

Comment: It looks like it is trying to connect to ‘localhost’ which won’t be possible by AWS easily. What services have been provisioned exactly, could you describe your setup? Is it AWS API Gateway -> lambda -> DynamoDB?  You can for many use-cases just directly connect API Gateway -> DynamoDB (service integration) without the lambda (compute) element. Or is it just lambda -> DynamoDB you have provisioned? There are some good tutorials and IaC (Infrastructure as Code) examples here: https://serverlessland.com/ (patterns, in SAM)

Comment: @LeighMathieson i have updated my question with more details, can you please look into the same

Comment: Please show the source of the lambda function. Seems you are trying to access your dynamodb on `localhost:8008` which will probably work if you work on your development machine but not when you deploy to aws ...

Comment: @coderman Your questions should be self contained. Nobody is interested in scanning through your entire repositiory for eventually finding an error ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the culprit , it was the env variable that i set in local

[image]